# Jetpack compose onClick and onLongPress with hover animation

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have the following card

```
@Composable
fun GeneralCard(mOnClick: () -> Unit, mContent: @Composable () -> Unit, mModifier: Modifier) {
val tooltipState = remember { PlainTooltipState() }
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
Card(
    onClick = {
        mOnClick()
    },
    modifier = mModifier
        .then(Modifier.padding(top = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.default_padding_smallest), start = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.default_padding_small))),
       // .pointerInput(Unit) {
          //  detectTapGestures(
               // onTap = { mOnClick() },
                //onLongPress = {
                 //   scope.launch { tooltipState.show() }
                //}
        //    )
       // },
    shape = RoundedCornerShape(dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.default_card_radius)),
    elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(defaultElevation = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.default_card_elevation), pressedElevation = 0.dp),
) {
    mContent()
    CustomPlainTooltipBox(mTooltipState = tooltipState) {}
}
```

}

If i use it just like that i have onClick() working and pressed animation (using card elevetion). But i wana have also onLongPress action ( 2 actions on the same card); With long press i just wana show show PlainTooltipBox

If comment onClick action and uncomment the other code i get my actions but i lose pressed animation

Any suggestion ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Tooltips in Compose work a bit differently. You will have to use the `tooltipAnchor` modifier, which automatically adds support for long-press:

```
    PlainTooltipBox(tooltip = { Text("Tooltip") }) {
        Card(
            onClick = { },
            modifier = Modifier.tooltipAnchor()
        ) {
            Text("Content")
        }
    }
```

In general, `Card` is a Material component with no long-press support. If your Design System needs you to create a `Card`-like component with long-press support, consider creating your own version.